# How to maintain session timeout when user is inactive for 3 minutes in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to implement session timeout for 3 minutes.The actual way of working of session is when user is idle for 3 minutes then only user get log-out or session gets expire.

But the way session works in my asp.net application, it expires session when user is also active for 3 minutes.

I want to know what things to do for proper session handling.
My code sample is here

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login/LoginFrist.aspx" timeout="5" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Have you set Sliding Expiration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms slidingExpiration="true" timeout="3"></forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Put this in you web.config or update accordingly.

check out following for more detais

[Forms authentication timeout vs sessionState timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17812994/1381667)