# Website users have to log back in after about a 1-5 minutes of inactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

I took over developing a website using C# and for some reason the website keep asking the users to log back in after about a 1-5 minutes of inactivity. I checked the Web.config and the timeout set to 60

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".tgcpauth" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

I have tried this on Google Chrome and Firefox as well.

The final result I want is to kick them out after 30 minutes instead of few seconds.

Update: I tried to add `<sessionState timeout="30" />` to my code before and after the authentication section but it still log the users out after 10 minutes of being idle. I read somewhere that 10 minutes is the default time for IIS. If that's the case, then how do I know which version of IIS I am running and where do I find IIS? I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Now, if I don't have IIS installed, then should I install it and what good is it for my c# website?

Comment: so what you want? you want to remove this auto logging off after 5 minutes or wanna add it?

Comment: In IIS you can set an idle time-out for the App pool.  Your users would be logged out once this expires.  Maybe that's a place to check?  Default is 20 mins I think

Comment: Something like that. I want to keep it active for 30 minutes or so

Comment: @David Greilach, where is IIS and what is it?

Comment: IIS is the server that is running the website. Depending on what version of windows server you're using it will look different, but it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: You might want to look at [Forms authentication timeout vs sessionState timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17812994/215552) as well.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking at this question, I found out that I cannot do anything on this since the website is hosted on GoDaddy and another copy on HostGator on a shared server and we have no control over the application timeout pool.