# Change ASP.NET session timeout programmatically

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

Here is a new requirement that I need help with. Our users request that 2 minutes before the session timeout, warn them. (i can use a global javascript to check on every page since once a page is loaded, the session reset and by default, another 20 minutes is extended). at the 18th minute, a javascript popup shows up, asking the user "You have two minutes left before being logged off. Do you want to extend the session"?

Up to here, all is fine. But then once they hit "Extend it", then what? I don't want to refresh the page because the data they've already entered will be lost. Is Ajax needed? If so, what is the programmatic way to extend the current session? (not modifying web.config just to be clear)

Also, say they are talking to someone and did not see the javascript confirmation during the 2 minute. Is there anyway to "hold" the session, till the user decides to do something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working on a similar problem. With ASP.Net every call back to the sever resets the session timeout period. So a Ajax call is going to be your best bet.

As for holding the session, are you actually storing anything in the Session object that needs to be maintained? Or when you say session do you mean the period that the user is authenticated for? If it is truly Session and you are not storing data then it shouldn't matter id it expires. You may want to take a look ar the below link.

[Forms authentication timeout vs sessionState timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout)