# How to extend AuthCookie expiration time when page refresh is refreshed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I set an AuthCookie in Login Action Method like this

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,true);
```

and in the Global.asax file I put the refresh code, (this will be executed after each action method authentication)

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;

 HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, true);
 var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
 var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,                                                                    
 ticket.Name,ticket.IssueDate,                                       
 ticket.Expiration,true,"new user data",ticket.CookiePath);

 cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
 cookie.Expires = newticket.Expiration.AddHours(24);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
}
```

But it's not working and it log out after a small period of time, although when I check that cookie with through browser settings, the expiration time was set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

probably there is a value set for the timeout of the logged user/session in **Web.config**', something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="10" />
</authentication>
```

You could get some useful info about forms sessions from here:
[Forms authentication timeout vs sessionState timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout)