# Web Forms Login Timeout

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, web-config, asp.net-identity

I have created an out-of-the-box Web Forms 4.5.2 project with Individual User Accounts. I cannot get the login timeout to work. I updated the Web.config to set the timeout to 12 mins:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="12" slidingExpiration="true" 
        requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

I explicitly set the session timeout to 20 mins, even though I presume this would be the default:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="20">
```

It is my [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout) that with `slidingExpiration` set to true that if the time elapsed is [greater than half](https://itworksonmymachine.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout/) the session time, the timeout resets on a browser refresh. Aside from the `slidingExpiration`, the timeout just isn't working as I am still logged in when refreshing the browser after 12 minutes.

When this didn't work, I looked at the Startup.Auth.cs file and changed a time interval there to 12 mins also. I presumed this related to the expiration of the cookie:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = 
                SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager,
                ApplicationUser>(validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
```

I'm using a locally-installed instance of SQL Server 2014:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
    connectionString="Server=XXX;Database=abc;user ID=myself;password=myself123" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In IIS, session state is set to "In process" and cookie settings as follows:

[image]

Still not working. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I added a self-signed cert on my local dev machine, but still couldn't get timeout to work; constantly logged in. Do I have to write specific code to get this functionality? I've only worked with the old membership system up to now and am not very familiar with Owin/Katana/Identity/EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, though I really need to ramp up on OWIN/Katana.

First of all, I commented out the following from the Web.config because it was only used in the older membership system:

```
<!--<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="true" />-->
```

Next, I followed [this article](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/) to configure the authentication timeout in the Startup.cs code:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
           OnValidateIdentity = 
           SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
             validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
             regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
    });
```

**Important:** In order to make this work, I had to manually delete the old cookies in browser dev tools.

**UPDATE**

Just for clarification, the forms entry in the Web.config file is still used by the Identity membership system. You can set a global timeout there, but if you want more granular control then use the code snippet above.