# Is it possible to make auto lock screen in ASP.NET-MVC-5 Razor View?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I Was thinking if i can make my admin website auto lock when the admin/user don't do anything between 15 minutes in razor view ?

Answer (score 0):

you might be mean the timeout? so basically if user don't do nothing during period of time, they will be automatically log out?. if that what you mean you can use form auth timeout or session timeout based on how your authentication works. 
then you can customize it using signalr or javascript timer to automatically call logout screen if their authentication is timeout.

find out more about form vs session timeout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout)